# Firefox fast version changes

Tags: firefox, version

Why did Firefox main versions start to grow so fast after 2011 april (FF4)?
It is version 13 now and rapidly growing.

I read the Wikipedia article about it, which says that they wanted that users always have an up-to-date version of Firefox. But why are minor versions not appropriate? Like 4.1, 4.14, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was to keep up with chromes naming scheme for their updates, essentially uses naturally thinking bigger changes were made with a major revision change vs. a minor one.